# VerificationSMSCode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'phone'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

#### Hello everyone! I'm working on a big project with Django Rest and I'm totally stuck with this one.

The project is something like Social network and I don't know why but everything seems to be correct, but every time I do "POST" method in the browser while debugging I see this error. I can provide you more information if you need it.

## urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from auth2.api.views import SendCodeView, VerifyCodeView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = []
router.register(r'code_send', SendCodeView, basename='code_send')
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header
from rest_framework import generics, status, views
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from auth2.api.serializers import SendCodeSerializer, VerifyCodeSerializer
from auth2.models import VerificationSMSCode
from core.api.serializers import UserSerializer


User = get_user_model()
logger = logging.getLogger('logzio')


class SendCodeView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = VerificationSMSCode.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SendCodeSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print('DEBUG ' + request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        logger.info(f'send code log', extra=request.data)

        VerificationSMSCode.create(serializer.user)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from auth2.utils import get_random_code
from core.models import User


class VerificationSMSCode(models.Model):
    STATUS_PENDING = 'pending'
    STATUS_DELIVERED = 'delivered'
    STATUS_ON_THE_WAY = 'on_the_way'

    user = models.ForeignKey('core.User', related_name='verification_sms_codes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.IntegerField(default=get_random_code)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)

    code_sent_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    code_sent_error = models.TextField(blank=True)

    sms_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    sms_status = models.CharField(default=STATUS_ON_THE_WAY, max_length=200, blank=True)

    delivered_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    code_used_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user):
        old_code = cls.objects.filter(user=user, phone=user.phone, code_used_at__isnull=True)
        if old_code:
            old_code.update(code_sent_at=None)
            return old_code.first()
        else:
            obj = cls.objects.create(user=user, phone=user.phone)
            return obj
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from auth2.api import consts
from auth2.models import VerificationSMSCode
from chat.models import Chat
from core.models import User


class SendCodeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone = serializers.IntegerField()

    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid_credentials": consts.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_ERROR,
        "inactive_account": consts.INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
        "invalid_code": consts.INVALID_CODE_ERROR,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None

    def validate(self, attrs):

        self.user, user_created = User.objects.get_or_create(phone=attrs['phone'])
        if user_created:
            chat = Chat.objects.create(title='Поддержка')
            chat.users.add(self.user)
            support_user = User.objects.filter(is_support=True).first()
            if support_user:
                chat.users.add(support_user)
        if not self.user.is_active:
            self.fail('inactive_account')

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return VerificationSMSCode.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I am trying to send a phone number which is where I'm sending random 4-digit code to and it fails.

#### If you have any ideas about how to fix this, please share.

## UPD1

Here is the full Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/code_send/

Django Version: 2.2.12
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'drf_yasg',
 'mptt',
 'django_mptt_admin',
 'django_extensions',
 'auth2',
 'bcard',
 'chat',
 'core',
 'filestorage',
 'ckeditor',
 'fcm_django',
 'dbbackup']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'core.middleware.RequestLoggerMiddleware',
 'core.middleware.UpdateLastOnlineMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  114.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in create
  19.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in perform_create
  24.         serializer.save()

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in save
  212.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "D:\Projects\backend\auth2\api\serializers.py" in create
  39.         return VerificationSMSCode.objects.create(**validated_data)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  420.         obj = self.model(**kwargs)

File "D:\Projects\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __init__
  501.                 raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/auth/code_send/
Exception Value: VerificationSMSCode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'phone'
```

Comment: [auth page](https://imgur.com/a/JO97xn9)
[post page](https://imgur.com/IUbOL5U)
[error](https://imgur.com/a/BjRKlfy)

Comment: Show us the full error traceback and add add textual information **to the question** itself **as text**.

Comment: @KlausD. Done, Sir!

Comment: You are doing a `create(user=user, phone=user.phone)` but the model has no `phone`. And BTW it should be stored on the `user` already.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes `user` already has phone object, and I tried without `phone=user.phone`. It is still the same error.

Comment: Did you fix the `filter()` as well and the `create()` in the serializer?